# Swap Linked list pairwise

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

```
public ListNode SwapPairs(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        var newHead = head.next;
        ListNode a = head; 
        ListNode b = head.next;
        ListNode prev = null;

        while(a != null && b != null) {
            a.next = b.next;
            b.next = a;

            if(prev != null)    
                prev.next = b;
            if(a.next == null)
                break;
            b = a.next.next;
            prev = a;
            a = a.next;
        }

        return newHead;
    }
```

This code is from leetcode, this one works but what i didnt understand is the use of the prev variable in this code, we are not assigning any values of prev to a or b, but without that the code dosent work, I am not sure wheather this a dumb question or am i not paying attention to anything important. Thanks

Comment: Use a debugger to see what values it holds through iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prev` does not need to be assigned to any variable. We are using it to track `a` and updating the reference's `next` property. It's used for making sure the previous swap chains up with the current swap correctly.

For example, in the 2nd iteration, we want to make sure `1.next` points to `4` instead of `3` like it did in the 1st iteration. This can be done be tracking a reference to the previous element of the current pair `prev` and updating `prev.next` by reference.

```cs
Original:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL

1st Iteration:
2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL

2nd Iteration:
2 -> 1 [->] 4 -> 3 -> NULL
```